# WCF Duplex - How to find Client's Callback URL?

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

How to find the Client's Callback URL for a duplex HTTP binding, from within the service (WCF 3.5)?

Appreciate any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the callback to the client in a duplex channel what you do is within the method that was invoked on the service you would call

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbackContract>();
```

where ICallbackContract is replaced with the actual callback contract name.

Edit:
Not sure what you mean by the phrase Clients Callback URL.  If you mean the address of the client that could be obtained via:

```
EndpointAddress clientAddress = OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress;
```

Comment: But that doesn't give me the URI of the client... Trying to find an alternate method of identifying client call back channels using URI. Original problem is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839311/wcf-custombinding-duplex-binaryencoding-no-security-cannot-call-back

Answer (score 2):

You normally find it trough

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<T>()
```

Where T is the type of the CallBack interface defined in the contract.

Comment: thanks Phil.. I couldn't figure out how to get the client URI though.. see my comment above..